Unable to build "WixSharp Setup - Bootstrapper (WiX4)" project
I am very new to WixSharp. When I create WixSharp project from template I am getting the following errors:

1>Source base directory: C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\WixSharp Setup6\WixSharp Setup6
1>wix.exe : error WIX0144: The extension 'WixToolset.UI.wixext' could not be found. Checked paths: WixToolset.UI.wixext, C:\Users\Robert.wix\extensions\WixToolset.UI.wixext\5.0.0\wixext4\WixToolset.UI.wixext.dll
1>
1>----------------------------------------------------------
1>
1>Wix project file has been built: C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\WixSharp Setup6\WixSharp Setup6\setup.wxs
1>
1>wix.exe : error WIX0144: The extension 'WixToolset.Netfx.wixext' could not be found. Checked paths: WixToolset.Netfx.wixext, C:\Users\Robert.wix\extensions\WixToolset.Netfx.wixext\5.0.0\wixext4\WixToolset.Netfx.wixext.dll
1>Cannot build C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\WixSharp Setup6\WixSharp Setup6\setup.wxs
1>C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\WixSharp Setup6\WixSharp Setup6\WixSharp Setup6.csproj(27,5): error MSB3073: The command "cd .
1>C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\WixSharp Setup6\WixSharp Setup6\WixSharp Setup6.csproj(27,5): error MSB3073: set ide=true
1>C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\WixSharp Setup6\WixSharp Setup6\WixSharp Setup6.csproj(27,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Users\Robert\source\repos\WixSharp Setup6\WixSharp Setup6\bin\Debug\net472\WixSharp Setup6.exe"" exited with code -1.
1>Done building project "WixSharp Setup6.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build completed at 10:56 and took 06,296 seconds ==========

dotnet tool install --global wix --version 4.0.0
wix extension add -g WixToolset.UI.wixext

At the time of writing, the "WixSharp Setup - Bootstrapper (WiX4)" template still uses the WixSharp_wix4 Nuget version 2.1.2 which contains a known regression. You need to update to 2.1.6 or greater to get the fix.
Open the NuGet package manager for your project, select WixSharp_wix4 and click "Update".

